# R: How to merge duplicate rows based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I’m trying to merge/add the totals in one column based on two separate columns.

It is a data.frame and I believe dplyr will do what I am looking for but need some guidance.

What I have at the moment is below;

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is below;

[image]

If there is no count for one status, it should just be 0 as some will just have a single status. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `library(dplyr) library(tidyr) df %>%
 group_by(product, status) %>%
 summarise_all(sum) %>%
 spread(status, number, fill = 0)`. But please use `dput()` instead of posting pictures of your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example ...

```
# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  number = c(750,100,250,250,350),
  product = c('car','car','car','ball','ball'),
  status = c('s','s','o','s','o')
)
# Create crosstab
xtabs(number ~ product + status, df)
```